# Can't fill a shape in After Effects (imported from XD)

Tags: after-effects, color, shape

I created some User Interface in Adobe XD including some shapes with blur and color each one. In XD everything looks OK, like:

[image]

But, when i Export that to After Effects (Adobe XD lets you export artboards directly from it to After Effects), this shape lose the color! Example:

[image]

Why is this happening? This is the configurations shown in After Effects for this shape:

[image]

Someone can help me?